# Set ListView Item Text Color to Black - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, textcolor

I am trying to style my `ListView` so that the `Item` `Text Color` is Black.
I have tried to put `android:textColor="#000000"` and it is still not working.
The background is White which is what I want.

How would I make the `ListView` Item Text Color Black via XML or Programatically?

Comment: I do not have any code other than the AXML which has nothing in it about `textColor`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your custom adapter.

```
TextView text = new TextView(context);
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("any hex value of a color"));
```